# Wieso sprengt man Rasenflächen?

Tags: etymology, verb

Googles Resultate bezüglich der Herkunft waren mittelprächtig.  Es *scheint* mir, dass es sich mit *in die Luft jagen* (dem anderen *sprengen*, das sehr bekannt ist) die Herkunft teilt.  Aber wie die genau aussieht, also wo und wann die Differenzierung stattfand, das wurde mir nicht klar.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**„Sprengen“** ist ein sehr altes deutsches Wort, das schon im Althochdeutsch geläufig war:

> ahd. **sprengen** *verbreiten, bespritzen, beflecken* (8. Jh.), mhd. **sprengen** *(das Pferd) springen lassen, galoppieren, (be)spritzen, streuen, (mit Farbe) sprenkeln*<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=sprengen)</sup>

Dabei ist *„sprengen“* das Kausativum von *„springen“* (also *„springen machen“*). Dabei bedeutet *„den Rasen sprengen“* hier nicht, dass man den Rasen springen lässt (sowie ein Sprengstoff die festen Bestandteile springen ließe), sondern dass man das Wasser über den Rasen springen lässt. *„Springen“* und Wasser finden sich auch heute noch im *„Springbrunnen“* oder der *„Springflut“*.

Die eigentliche Bedeutung von *„sprengen“* beim Wässern des Gartens und beim Sprengen eines Gebäudes mit Dynamit ist aber dennoch dieselbe.

Comment: So in ungefähr hatte ich da vermutete (DWDS hatte ich auch als prominenten Treffer gecheckt).  Das mit Springbrunnen/Springflut hilft ungemein. :D

Comment: Siehe auch `er versprengte das Wasser über den Rasen`.

Comment: "Kausativum"? o_O

Comment: @A.B.: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kausativ

Answer (score 9):

Beide Wörter (springen und sprengen) sind miteinander verwandt. *Sprengen* ist der [Kausativ](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kausativ) von *springen*, d. h., mit *sprengen* wird das Springen veranlasst (Verursachung der Handlung). Sprachgeschichtlich aus dem Althochdeutschen *springan* bzw. *sprengan* entwickelt.<sup>([1](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS36927))</sup>

Es gibt eine Reihe ähnlicher Paare, wie z. B.:

- fallen / fällen
- fließen / flößen
- liegen / legen

Answer (score 0):

woher kommt "den Rasen sprengen"?

Obwohl diese Frage schon älter ist, möchte ich dennoch etwas dazu sagen. Wenn ich in  DWDS den Artikel von Pfeifer lese, habe ich das Gefühl, dass man da nicht so alles richtig im Griff hat.
Was mich hier so erstaunt, ist das lateinisch spargere nicht als Quelle genannt wird.

Lat. spargere hat die Bedetung (aus)streuen, Flüssiges: sprengen, verspritzen.
Zwar sind der lat. Wortstamm sparg- und der deutsche Wortstamm spreng-  doch so verschieden, dass einem das lat. Wort nicht gleich als Quelle einfällt.
Nimmt man aber das Kompositum di-sperg-ere, kommt man  mit dem lat. Wortstamm aber doch schon sehr nahe an den deutschen Wortstamm spreng- heran.

Der deutsche Stamm enthält ein n-Infix und das r erscheint vor dem Vokal.
Positionwechsel von r (r-Metathese) ist eine sehr häufige Erscheinung, und n wird nicht selten eingeschoben oder es fällt aus.
Ich kann nicht beurteilen, ob im Deutschen das n eingeschoben wurde oder ob es im Lateinischen ausgefallen ist, vielleicht könnte da die Indogermanistik 
eine Antwort geben.
Aber es scheint mir doch sehr wahrscheinlich, das deutsches sprengen in Sinne von den Rasen sprengen mit lat. spargere/spergere in Zusammenhang steht.

Das lat. Verb zeigt mit der Zeit auffallend viele Bedeutungsentwicklungen: säen - zerstreuen versprengen - zerreißen - werfen schleudern schießen  und Ähnliches.
So dürfte es auch zu der deutschen Anwendung "eine Brücke sprengen gekommen sein.

Ob deutsches springen mit sprengen zusammenhängt scheint mir sehr zweifelhaft. Das könnte woanders herkommen. und mir scheint, dass im Bereich sprengen und springen noch lange nicht 
alles geklärt ist.

Comment: In manchen Regionen wird noch heute *springen* wie *sprengen* ausgesprochen - auch das weist auf eine  gemeinsame Etymologie hin.

Comment: wieso soll _spargere_ eine "Quelle" sein, wenn die Wörter einen gemeinsamen Ursprung haben?

Comment: Interessant. Vgl. auch sporadisch, https://www.dwds.de/wb/sporadisch und Spore, https://www.dwds.de/wb/Spore.