# What is the origin of the word "Ursprung"?

Tags: etymology

From which words does the German *Ursprung* originate? In Portuguese we have the translation *origem (origin),* but I need to know more about this word.

I tried to separate the *ur* from the *sprung* to see if I could get a hint, but I’m not sure if I can do this. I discovered that *ur* can mean *origin,* and translating *sprung* I got *leap.* Can I consider it?

Comment: If you know enough German, then this is helpful: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/startGlobalSearch.tcl?stichwort=Ursprung

Comment: So you're asking about the Ursprung of the word `Ursprung`?

Comment: Pfeifer has an answer: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ursprung#et-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the German prefix ur- a lot has been written. But what I read is not satisfying.
First of all ur- has different sources.

Urlaub - this ur- is connected with er- as in Erlaubnis/erlauben. Urlaub was a military term and it was the permission to leave the military service for some time.

Urzeit - in most cases ur- has the meaning of "earliest/first". I think this ur- is a variant or vor- with drop of v and change of o to u. I would connect it with "vorderster"
(English first and German vorderst-er/erst-er are related).

German vor is related with Latin pro and its variants pre-/pri-/por-and Latin pri-mus and Greek pro:tos meaning the first.

Ultimately I think the idea of ur- is "the foremost".

Ursprung
I think this is the place where water springs up from the ground to form a rivulet. And I think this ur- is connected with "empor", a variant of "vor", meaning "hervor" out of.

Answer (score 10):

You are right in separating "ur-" and "Sprung".

The prefix "ur-" was originally used in the meaning of "from" or "out of".

The word "Sprung" did in Old German also have the meaning of "source", especially water source. Remains of this meaning is e.g. still used in words like "Springbrunnen" (fountain) - literary a well or fountain fed by a water source.

Combining the terms gives a rough translation of "from the source".

Comment: I'm not convinced of the etymological explanation for *Springbrunnen*, do you have any references? After all, a *Springbrunnen* is a special type of "Brunnen" - while all kinds of "Brunnen" in some way work as origins of water, the distinguishing mark of a *Springbrunnen* is that the water is expelled with some pressure, usually not straight downwards, often up into the air - i.e. as opposed to other types of *Brunnen* that are just as well an *Ursprung* of water, a *Springbrunnen* makes the water "jump" (springen) into the air. At least that's my native speaker's impression.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Take a look at [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3392/2594).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Thanks, that confirms my suspicion that *Springbrunnen* is not that closely related with *entspringen* (originate), and is rather linked to the movement *springen* (jump) of the water - as it is expressed in the accepted answer to the question you linked: "dass man das Wasser über den Rasen springen läßt. "Springen" und Wasser findet sich auch heute noch im "Springbrunnen"".

Comment: Compare http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=spring&searchmode=none

Comment: Ich habe keine Quelle für die ursprüngliche Bedeutung von Springbrunnen, habe aber vielleicht zu schnell einen Zusammenhang zwischen "Springbrunnen" und Engl. "wellspring" gesehen. Latein "fons", wovon Wörter wie fountain und Fontäne abgeleitet sind bedeutet auch eigentlich nur "Quelle", ohne besondere Benennung der Wasserbewegungen. Ursprünglich dienten die Springbrunnen doch auch eher der Trinkwasserversorgung (Quelle)?

Comment: Kluge *Etymologisches Wörterbuch* confirms the relation between Ursprung (including the prefix) and a source (of water). According to them, „Ursprung“ is the noun formed for „erspringen“, which would be called „entspringen“ in modern German. The prefix „Ur-“ in nouns seems to often correspond to „er-“ in verbs, according to the text on that prefix. E.g. „Urlaub“ relates to „erlauben“.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Möglich, ursprünglich dienten aber auch andere Brunnen, die keine Springbrunnen sind, der Trinkwasserversorgung, sodass dies kein potenziell namensgebendes Alleinstellungsmerkmal darstellen kann.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're almost there. You're correct about "Ur" and "Sprung", but the latter is also related to "entspringen" (originate, rise up, spring up) and the english word "spring" as the season everything "starts". If you leap, you have the connotation of "starting something new", as you consciously initiate a process which can't be stopped easily.

Comment: Considering *Sprung,* take a look at [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3392/2594). I would also guess that the English usage of *spring* for *Quelle* has the same origin.

Answer (score 1):

The word "**Ursprung**" comes from the Old High German word: *irspringan* which evolved to the Middle High German word: *ursprunc*. 
**Ur** (prefix, adj.) = ancient, primal, original. 
**Sprung** (noun,masculine) = well, spring, source.
And the word means "primal" or "ancestral" origin and it is a parental/maternal term. In the English language the term **offspring** (noun) is more popular. So, you can say the Ursprung is where the offspring come from :-D

Answer (score -2):

Just adding to the already excellent answers.

Vater, Großvater, Urgroßvater, Ururgroßvater, Urururgroßvater. 
Ursprünglich kommt der Ururururururururururgroßvater aus Afrika. Die Urururururururururururgroßmutter teilen wir uns alle. Ursprünglich kommen wir alle aus dem selben Ei.

Unser Ursprung ist die vor Urzeiten existierende Ursuppe. Die Ursache für den Beginn des Lebens ist ein Überschuss von Energie.

Urig interessant dass. :D

Ob Urlaub - Erlaubnis zur (temporären) Rückkehr zum Ursprung bedeutet?

Comment: Klingt als bräuchte da jemand Urlaub. SCNR

Comment: Falls mich demnächst jemand nach der *Urzeit* fragt, bist du es schuld. ;)